# Using su which user was I?

Tags: linux, su

I use su when I often need to set proper permissions when copying files etc, but forget if I used su to get there, ex:

```
root@host> su bob
bob@host> copy folderA folderB
```

But sometimes I forget if I logged in as bob or if I was root and su'd to become bob, make since? So a full example:

```
bob@host> su
....
root@host> su bob
bob@host> cp folderA folderB
....
bob@host> ????????
```

Now at this point I forget if I am directly logged into the computer or if I am su'd in, I can press CTRL-D which would tell me if I was root, but if not I get logged out.

I understand sudo is good and secure and all, but I'm curious if there is a way to do this without avoiding using su.

Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by looking at the running processes in a tree.

```
ps axjf
```

Look through the long output till you find something like this:

```
    1  2426  2426  2426 ?           -1 S<s      0   3:35 /usr/sbin/sshd
 2426  7024  7024  7024 ?           -1 S<s      0   0:00  \_ sshd: user1 [priv]
 7024  7029  7024  7024 ?           -1 S<    1002   0:00      \_ sshd: user1@pts/0
 7029  7030  7030  7030 pts/0    29857 S<s   1002   0:00          \_ -bash
 7030 29831 29831  7030 pts/0    29857 S<       0   0:00              \_ su
29831 29833 29833  7030 pts/0    29857 S<       0   0:00                  \_ bash
29833 29845 29845  7030 pts/0    29857 S<    1017   0:00                      \_ su user2
29845 29846 29846  7030 pts/0    29857 S<    1017   0:00                          \_ bash
29846 29857 29857  7030 pts/0    29857 R<+   1017   0:00                              \_ ps axjf
```

You can see i logged in as user1 and then su'd to root and then su'd to user2

This command worked fine for me on debian.  If you use a differnt version of linux and it doesn't work just check the man page for ps and search for the word  'tree'

Comment: perfect! I was suspecting that I would have no solution

Comment: ps af seems to do the same, but not showing as much output

Answer (score 3):

You can use `whoami` to tell you the effective userid and you can use `who am i` to tell you who you logged in as e.g.

```
$ who am i
iain     pts/0        2011-09-15 17:33 (192.168.1.104)
$ whoami
iain

$ su -
# whoami
root
# who am i
iain     pts/0        2011-09-15 17:33 (192.168.1.104)

# su - user1
$ whoami
user1
$ who am i
iain     pts/0        2011-09-15 17:33 (192.168.1.104)
```

Comment: this is good to detect if you logged on as a user, but it's possible to su to Iain and not know if you were logged in that way or su'd

Answer (score 0):

last command can display last logged in user.

Comment: yes, but I don't think "su user" is logged and I wouldn't know if I logged in as the user or if I su'd into that user